# Can I use curio with sanic. Why not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, sanic

I tried to use async raw socket in my `sanic` application on `Python 3.6` 
And was really surprised that async functions from `curio` doesn't work in sanic async context. Minimal proof of concept:

```
import curio
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import text
app = Sanic(__name__)


@app.route('/')
async def index(request):
    sock = await curio.open_connection("google.com", 443, ssl=True)
    resp = await sock.recv(1024)
    return text(resp)


app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5001)
```

This code generates core dump on any http request

```
$ python3 test2.py 
2017-04-17 17:33:13,266: INFO: Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:5001
2017-04-17 17:33:13,270: INFO: Starting worker [93060]
Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked

Current thread 0x00007fc57706e480 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/linecache.py", line 165 in lazycache
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/traceback.py", line 345 in extract
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/traceback.py", line 497 in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/traceback.py", line 117 in format_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/traceback.py", line 163 in format_exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/handlers.py", line 93 in default
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/handlers.py", line 70 in response
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 472 in handle_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/server.py", line 410 in serve
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 561 in run
  File "test2.py", line 14 in <module>
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linking this question with github issue, that has been raised by OP.

[Using curio in sanic controller](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/issues/651).

Sum up(from issue comments):

> From the official Curio docs:
>   "Curio can also submit work to the asyncio event loop with the provision that it must be running separately in a different thread."
>
> [Look at this issue](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio/issues/190)
>
> Curio's main implementation of events is a queue, not an event loop. You're trying to spawn tasks inside the same thread Sanic (and the event loop) are running from.